# How can I display a String from sharedpreferences in an Android popup menu?

Tags: android

I tried to display a simple String, but I can only see something like:

android.widget.EditText{3cdce91dVFED..CL.F.......0,79-758..

```
//works fine
String userId = "42";
popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, 0, 2, userId );

//is showing the code from above
String userId = sharedPreferences.getString("userId", "");
popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, 0, 2, userId );
```

I used a Class with static String fields as well and got the same result.

I use two different actions, one form to insert the userId and one action where I want to show the userId within a popup Menu. What would be the best method to solve this problem?

I save the value into the shared preferences with the following code:

```
EditText userId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);           
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userId", userId.toString()).commit();
```

Comment: show me the code how you are storing value in shared preferences?

Comment: How are you saving preferences?

Comment: sorry I already updated my answer, so you can see how I save the preferences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userId", userId.toString()).commit();
```

to

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userId", userId.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like these 2 methods to save and retrive sharedpreferences

### Set

```
private void updateStatus(String key, String content){
        try{
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preference_key),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(getString(key), content);
            editor.apply(); //Executes in background
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle excpetion
        }                   
}
```

### Get

```
public static Boolean getPreference(Context context, String key){

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_preference_key),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getBoolean(context.getString(key), "");
}
```

Note:
You may want to change `context.getString(R.string.shared_preference_key)` with something else, try replacing it with `"example"` just to make a test.